# Does neck bridge / roll targets all neck muscles?

Tags: muscle, neck

Does the [neck bridge/roll à la Mike Tyson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvQTyHE2c5M) target all neck muscles, and can it be used as a sole neck exercise,or should it be combined with other neck exercises?

My goal is not to simply make my neck big, but to strengthen the all neck muscles.

Comment: For clarity, we're talking about this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvQTyHE2c5M

Comment: @Alec yes exactly this